# Thermal pad in LED design

Tags: led, pcb-design

I am using Olson square 1 W LEDs, and I am wondering do I need to dissipate heat through thermal pads and how should I connect the thermal pads(their size and are they connected to ground?)

Here is the datasheet recommended footprint:
[image].

Comment: Might you have forgotten to include something relevant?

Comment: No, just edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: Please look at “CREE Thermal Management of XLamp® LEDs Application Note” via google. They explain everything in detail, show you what’s not enough, what’s just right, what’s too much and why. Great resource. https://cree-led.com/media/documents/XLampThermalManagement.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have essentially 3 pads in the suggested footprint which are soldered to the LED: an upper, a lower, and an H-shaped middle. The upper and lower are actually the electrical connection points to the LED, and MUST be connected to the power supply. They also conduct heat away from the LED. The middle pad is thermal only, and can be left floating.

As for whether or not you NEED to use thermal pads, that depends on the amount of power you're dissipating. If you want to push 100 mW through the LED you can probably do without thermal pads. Of course, if you do that you can just go with a smaller LED. If you want to dissipate 1 watt, you don't necessarily need thermal pads - for instance, if you're blinking for 0.1 seconds every second. Or if you don't care how long the LED lasts before it dies.

Look - if the manufacturer suggests thermal pads, for Heaven's sake use them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The led will be fully on, The H shaped thermal only pad has no dimensions specified in the datasheet. so I am wondering can I set their dimensions arbitrary.
Also when I downloaded the pcb library for the component from SnapEDA the middle thermal only pad had no extra copper like the H shape above.

Answer (score 2):

If the "H" region is electrically isolated (at ground potential, or not connected to any voltage), then use several vias to connect it to an underlying (opposite side) GROUND PLANE to dump the heat.

A via with 1:1 ratio of periphery_to_height has 70 degree C per watt Thermal Resistance, using standard PCB foil (1.4 mils thick, or 35 microns, 1 ounce per square foot) and assuming the Via hole interior is also plated to 1.4 mils.

In 1/16th inch PCB stock, that via would be 1/16 height and 1/48 in diameter.

If you used 5 of those vias, the thermal resistance would be 70/5 = 14 degree C per watt, and your LED should last much longer.

Answer (score 1):

If the LED will be fully on, at full capacity all the time, then I strongly recommend extending the thermal pads to the sides and add a heatsink.
The thermal pad starts below the led and can extended left and right toward small copper areas 10x10mm for example. These copper areas should not be covered with solder mask.

You should also add thermal vias connecting the thermal pads to the other side of the board where they will meet a large copper area. On the other side, you fix a heatsink applied to the large copper area. This copper area should also be without solder mask. The heatsink should be applied directly to the copper.

The heatsink can be an inexpensive standard aluminium profile. But the larger the better.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why the data sheet is extending the thermal pad (The H-Shaped) and still yet covering it with solder mask as in the second diagram.

Comment: Another question, would extending the thermal pad left and right toward small copper areas 10x10mm 'without connecting any heat sink' can help ?

Comment: Yes it will help. You can extend it further to 20x10mm for example. But the effect of more extention is limited. Drilling thermal vias and adding a heatsink on the other side will help much more.